# What's the best user login management when handling multiple login sources?

Tags: authentication, oauth, openid, facebook-login

I'm currently designing a website (on google app engine) in which user can register from multiple sources (classic registration, google account login, facebook login, or maybe OpenID or OAuth).

I'm a bit confused with all this, i don't know what's the best behavior for this.

- Should i try to associate accounts automatically when using the same email address ?
- Should i dissociate accounts (meaning that if you use Google login when you registrated with classic user/password, it will fail) ?
- Should i send verification emails for classical registration, or allow user to use the website and just send a "welcome" email ?

I'd like the website to be as easy as possible, but we may put some commercial features on it later. Do you have any advice on the user auth system to develop ?

Comment: This question is probably better suited for [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/). Having said that, have you looked at how Stackoverflow handles login (via openID) - I think it's one of the better and more user friendly authentication systems.